# Use NLTK RegexTokenizer to tokenize text and write it to a CSV

Tags: python, csv, unicode, nltk, tokenize

Thank you in advance for your help. I'm extremely lost. I'm trying to import a corpus and then have it print trigrams into a csv file with the frequency distribution and the relative frequency in two columns next to the first column that contains the entire trigram. But I don't understand RegexTokenizer well enough to do it. The code below gets 90% of the way there but the RegexTokenizer only looks for letters so it splits phrases with conjunctions like "don't go away" into trigrams: "don t go"

I need it to stop doing that. Without the RegexTokenizer the trigrams look like this: (u'middle', u'class', u'americans') I'd imagine you can use RegexTokenizer to find only the phrases between u' and ' but I don't know how to do that.

```
import nltk
import re
from nltk.corpus.reader.plaintext import PlaintextCorpusReader
from nltk import FreqDist
import math 
from decimal import *
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer, WhitespaceTokenizer
import csv

#this imports the text files in the folder into corpus called speeches
corpus_root = '/Users/root...'
speeches = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, '.*\.txt')

print "Finished importing corpus"

tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
raw = speeches.raw().lower()
tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(raw)
tgs = nltk.trigrams(tokens)
fdist = nltk.FreqDist(tgs)
minscore = 200
numwords = len(raw)
c = csv.writer(open("TPNngrams.csv", "wb"))
for k,v in fdist.items():
    if v > minscore:
        rf = Decimal(v)/Decimal(numwords)
        firstword, secondword, thirdword = k
        trigram = firstword + " " + secondword + " " + thirdword
        results = trigram,v,rf
        c.writerow(results)
        print firstword, secondword, thirdword, v, rf
```

And I also keep getting this error randomly:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa9' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the regex tokenizer, replace your tokenizer with something like:

```
text = "We have 15 billion dollars in gold in our treasury; we don't own an ounce."
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'(\w|\')+')
tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
# ['We', 'have', '15', 'billion', 'dollars', 'in', 'gold', 'in', 'our', 'treasury', 'we', "don't", 'own', 'an', 'ounce']
```

which handles conjunctions.

I'm not sure where the error is thrown (maybe provide more information?) but I'm guessing you're importing strange characters that Python doesn't know how to deal with. Try adding

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
```

at the very top of your .py file.